# Hard Water Deposits

Tags: water

I'm considering purchasing a water softener due to living in an area with very hard water.  Should I consider having my water lines flushed out prior to installing the softener?

Answer (score 1):

Up to you, personally, I just fitted it and carried on as normal.

But you can do the flush as you wish - I still have deposits but my water is very hard, however much reduced. Once a month cleaning the kettle is now once every 4 months or so...

Comment: Over time the internal deposits would slowly flush on their own, the “flush chemicals” always bothered me if I got everything out of the pipes but I have used them when the owner wanted but haven’t seen much difference after a couple of months.

Comment: @EdBeal well my system is still working after 6 years and no chemicals to deal with - except for those arriving in the water...